# Facing issue in selecting and deselecting tableview cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, select, deselect

I am showing pincodes in tableview, and when i select a cell then it should select and if i tap on the same cell again then it should deselect(while tapping cell should work like switch)

[image]

but with below code

**issue 1:** initially i am unable to select 1st row but after selecting any other row and then able to select 1st row.. why? where am i wrong?

**issue 2:** only one time i can select deselect the same row with two tapping if i tap 3rd time continuously then unable to select the same row, why?.. please guide

```
class PincodeModel{
var name: String?
var id: Int?
var isSelected: Bool

init(name: String?, id: Int?, isSelected: Bool) {
    self.name = name
    self.id = id
    self.isSelected = isSelected
}
}


class FilterViewController: UIViewController {

var pincodePreviousIndex: Int = -1
var pincodes = [PincodeModel]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    for pincode in pincodeList {
        self.pincodes.append(PincodeModel(name: pincode, id: 0, isSelected: false))
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubFilterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SubFilterTableViewCell
        cell.title.text = self.pincodes[indexPath.row].name

        if !self.pincodes.isEmpty {
            if self.pincodes[indexPath.row].isSelected == true {
                cell.tickImageView.image =  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "iconTick")
            }else {
                cell.tickImageView.image = UIImage()
            }
        }
    return cell
}

 // EDITED Code according to below answer
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   
    self.pincodes[indexPath.row].isSelected = !self.pincodes[indexPath.row].isSelected

if self.pincodes[indexPath.row].isSelected == true {
self.filterData.pincode = pincodes[indexPath.row].name ?? ""
}else {
self.filterData.pincode = ""
}
if pincodePreviousIndex > 0 && pincodePreviousIndex != indexPath.row {
pincodes[pincodePreviousIndex].isSelected = false
}
pincodePreviousIndex = indexPath.row

}
```

this is working as i want when i select from index = 1, but if i select first row(index = 0) then the right mark remains if i select another row, why?

o/p with edited code:

[image]

Comment: Are you allowing **multiple** selections? Or only a single selection, and you want to toggle selection when tapping the same row...  deselecting "the other selected row" (if there is one) at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For issue 1 - By using this line of code:

`var pincodePreviousIndex: Int = 0`

You cannot click the first row until you click another since

`pincodes[pincodePreviousIndex].isSelected = false`

Since you're defaulting to 0 in the beginning, that correlates to the first row.

For issue 2 - if you select row 2 (selected) and then select it again to deselect it: pincodePreviousIndex will hold the value of that row and then deselect it again with

`pincodes[pincodePreviousIndex].isSelected = false`

So even though you're selecting it it will deselect it.

I would do this at the top:
`var pincodePreviousIndex: Int = -1`

and at the bottom:

```
if pincodePreviousIndex > 0 && pincodePreviousIndex != indexPath.row {
    pincodes[pincodePreviousIndex].isSelected = false
}
```

Comment: Good explanation of the problem, but this is swift.  We don't need to use sentinel values. We have optionals. Declare `var pincodePreviousInstance: Int?` and then use conditional unwrapping.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple approaches you can take to save yourself some trouble.

First, set `.selectionStyle = .none` on your cells, and then in your cell class, override `setSelected(...)`. For example, I added an image view to my cell and gave it an empty-box as its image, and a checked-box as its highlighted image:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    imgView.isHighlighted = selected ? true : false
}
```

Now the cell appearance will reflect its selected state which is maintained by the table view.

Next, instead of `didSelectRowAt`, we'll implement `willSelectRowAt` ... if the cell is currently selected, we'll deselect it (and update our data):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    // is a row already selected?
    if let idx = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        if idx == indexPath {
            // tapped row is already selected, so
            //  deselect it
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
            //  update our data
            pincodes[indexPath.row].isSelected = false
            //  tell table view NOT to select the row
            return nil
        } else {
            // some other row is selected, so
            //  update our data
            //  table view will automatically deselect that row
            pincodes[idx.row].isSelected = false
        }
    }
    // tapped row should now be selected, so
    //  update our data
    pincodes[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
    //  tell table view TO select the row
    return indexPath
}
```

---

Here's a complete example:

```
class PincodeModel{
    var name: String?
    var id: Int?
    var isSelected: Bool
    
    init(name: String?, id: Int?, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}

class SelMethodTableViewController: UIViewController {

    var pincodes: [PincodeModel] = []
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    let infoView: UIView = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return v
    }()
    let infoTitle: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Info:"
        return v
    }()
    let infoLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 0..<20 {
            let pcm = PincodeModel(name: "\(i)", id: i, isSelected: false)
            pincodes.append(pcm)
        }

        [tableView, infoView, infoTitle, infoLabel].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        [infoTitle, infoLabel].forEach { v in
            infoView.addSubview(v)
        }
        [tableView, infoView].forEach { v in
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain the table view on right-side of view
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoView.topAnchor, constant: -16.0),

            // let's add a tappable "info" view below the table view
            infoView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            infoView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            infoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
            
            // add labels to infoView
            infoTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            infoTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            infoTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            //infoLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: infoView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
        ])

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        tableView.register(MyToggleCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "toggleCell")
        
        // just so we can see the frame of the table view
        tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showInfo(_:)))
        infoView.addGestureRecognizer(t)
        infoView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @objc func showInfo(_ g: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        var s: String = ""
        
        let selectedFromData = pincodes.filter( {$0.isSelected == true} )

        s += "Data reports:"
        if selectedFromData.count > 0 {
            selectedFromData.forEach { ob in
                let obID = ob.id ?? -1
                s += " \(obID)"
            }
        } else {
            s += " Nothing selected"
        }
        s += "\n"
        s += "Table reports: "
        if let selectedFromTable = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            selectedFromTable.forEach { idx in
                s += " \(idx.row)"
            }
        } else {
            s += " No rows selected"
        }
        infoLabel.text = s
    }
}

extension SelMethodTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pincodes.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "toggleCell", for: indexPath) as! MyToggleCell
        c.label.text = pincodes[indexPath.row].name
        c.selectionStyle = .none
        return c
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        // is a row already selected?
        if let idx = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            if idx == indexPath {
                // tapped row is already selected, so
                //  deselect it
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
                //  update our data
                pincodes[indexPath.row].isSelected = false
                //  tell table view NOT to select the row
                return nil
            } else {
                // some other row is selected, so
                //  update our data
                //  table view will automatically deselect that row
                pincodes[idx.row].isSelected = false
            }
        }
        // tapped row should now be selected, so
        //  update our data
        pincodes[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
        //  tell table view TO select the row
        return indexPath
    }
}

class MyToggleCell: UITableViewCell {
    let imgView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        return v
    }()
    let label: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        [imgView, label].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // give bottom anchor less-than-required
        //  to avoid auto-layout complaints
        let b = imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0)
        b.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32.0),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor),
            b,
            
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.trailingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        if let img1 = UIImage(systemName: "square"),
           let img2 = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.square") {
            imgView.image = img1
            imgView.highlightedImage = img2
        }
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        imgView.isHighlighted = selected ? true : false
    }
}
```

It will look like this:

[image]

When running:

- Tapping a row will select that row
- Tapping a different row will select the new row and deselect the currently selected row
- Tapping the already-selected row will deselect it
- Tapping the gray "info view" will report on the selection states from both the data and the table view

[image]

[image]

Note that if a selected row is scrolled out-of-view, it will remain selected (and will show selected when scrolled back into view) and the data and table view selection states will continue to be correct.

---

**Edit**

If we want to use `didSelectRowAt` (perhaps for other uses), we can "toggle" the selected row like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    
    // if the tapped row is already selected
    if let indexPathForSelectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
       indexPathForSelectedRow == indexPath {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        // calling .deselectRow(at: ...) does NOT trigger a call to didDeselectRowAt
        // so update our data here
        pincodes[indexPath.row].isSelected = false
        return nil
    }
    return indexPath
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("did select", indexPath)
    pincodes[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("did deselect", indexPath)
    pincodes[indexPath.row].isSelected = false
}
```